# Run function if query string is set to 1

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a little thing in wordpess where i want top call a specific function if a certain query string is set to 1. Like when `import_publish=1` i want to call a function.

Currently my code looks like this.

functions.php

```
<?php

add_action( 'admin_init', [ $this, 'process_import' ];

function process_import() {
  if( !isset( $_POST['import_publish'] ) && !isset( 
    $_POST['import_nonce'] ) ) {
    return;
  }

  if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['import_nonce'], 'mediabank_import' ) 
    || ! current_user_can( 
    'manage_options' ) ) {
    return;
  }
  // call some function
}

add_action('admin_menu', [ $this, 'mediabank_admin_menu' ] );

function mediabank_admin_menu() {
  add_submenu_page(
    'edit.php?post_type=' . MEDIABANK_POST_TYPE, 
    __( 'Mediabank Import', $this->domain ), 
    __( 'Import', $this->domain ), 
    'manage_options',
    '/import',
    [ $this, 'mediabank_render_import_page' ]
  );
}

function mediabank_render_import_page() {
   require_once( plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) . 'admin/templates/import.php' ); 
}

?>
```

import.php (holds the form,the import function itself i want to call in functions)

```
<div class="wrap">
  <?php echo '<h2>'.__('Import', $this->domain).'</h2>'; ?>
  <?php echo '<p>'.__('Import new posts/images by clicking the button below.', $this- 
 >domain).'</p>'; ?>
<form action="<?php echo admin_url( '?page=import' ); ?>" method="post">
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'mediabank_import', 'import_nonce' ); ?>
<input type="submit" name="import_publish" id="publish" class="button button-primary button- 
 large" value="Import">
</form>
</div>
```

So how would I go on doing this?

Comment: Instead of setting it as a query string parameter, why not pass it as a hidden field?

Comment: If you have a solution doing so, please post! I'm grateful for all help i can get. Just want to achieve what i explained. How it'd done is less important for me. @cabrerahector

Comment: What I meant was simply adding a hidden field to your form like this: `<input type="hidden" name="import_publish" value="1">`. That way you'll get your `$_POST['import_publish']` variable and use it as you see fit.

Comment: (Although I don't see why you'd need to do that, you already have a nonce field in there that you can use to verify that an "import" request has been submitted.)

Comment: Also: move your entire `// TODO, call the function` IF condition into your `process_import()` function. That's where you'd want to do this check (and run your import script).

Comment: @cabrerahector Hi, thanks for your help. Think i got it now. But this query. How do i know if it works or not? i mean its not present in the address bar. i want it to be set when the button is clicked.

Comment: @cabrerahector I have also edited the code to apply your suggested changes, see post.

Comment: Try adding `wp_die("Valid form submission");` right after `// call some function` and try submitting the form. If the nonce field is valid, you'll see "Valid form submission" (without the quotes) on screen.

Comment: @cabrerahector Yepp, that works. I would like if the user could stay on the same page tho and get a nice echo or something instead of a die when the submit is valid.

Comment: Then you'll need to change your approach and use AJAX instead: [WordPress AJAX API]( https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) (FYI: the article is aimed towards plugin developers but the API can be used by themes, too.)

Comment: That sounds like an approach that I'm a lot more confident in. I did not know you could do so in a wp custom plugin. thanks!